# No UI / exposure for seeing similar questions when asking from iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, asking-questions, ios-app, similar-questions

When asking a question through the iOS app (v. 0.1.24), the question just gets posted without any sort of chance to review similar questions. (This is shown on the iOS web app and desktop browsers on the full site in the right sidebar as you edit any question before posting it.)

Would it be possible to have new questions saved as drafts (ideally to the servers), and then present a second sheet with potential duplicates?

This would let someone compose a question and then encourage them to make sure it's not already machine matched with a similar post before it actually gets posted to the site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done!  When asking a question the app will display the four most similar questions (maybe I should add a screen for even more?) and let you jump back and forth between your draft and those questions using Arie's slick drafting UI.

[image: Screenshot showing the lifecycle of similar questions]

Comment: That looks very slick. What version on the app store will have this code?

Comment: @bmike 1.3.1, gonna ship mid May.

Comment: @bmike This has been implemented, are you going to accept the answer?