# Ask Question bar Android App

Tags: discussion, feature-request, android-app, asking-questions

I started using stack exchange recently and at that using the Android App. I asked a couple of duplicate questions intially.

Later when I first logged into the desktop browser to ask a question, I was dumbfounded to see that when I try to ask a question it suggests that I find my answer in these similar questions. I would have definitely avoided asking duplicate questions if this has showed up in the android app.

I am suggesting adding this feature of “similar questions” when asking a new question in the type question box. This would make android app much more effective especially to new users who are very concerned about their reputation, atleast till chat priviledge is awarded.

Comment: You can always perform a search before asking. But +1 because the "your question may already be answered here" toolbar strangely seems to be much more accurate.

Comment: I did search, but as you said, it is not as effective as that ask question bar search

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224282/no-ui-exposure-for-seeing-similar-questions-when-asking-from-ios-app?rq=1 (for the iOS app).